# Making extension class generic

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I have such a piece of code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace PricingCoefficientService.Extensions
{
    public static class IntExt
    {
        public static bool IsIn(this int integer, IEnumerable<int> collectionOfIntegers)
        {
            return collectionOfIntegers.Contains(integer);
        }
    }
}
```

it is an extension method extending int. I believe its functionality is obvious.

But what if I dont want to make it generic to make it usable for each value type or object?

any idea?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the method generic

```
public static bool IsIn<T>(this T value, IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    if (collection == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    }

    return collection.Contains(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
public static bool IsIn<T>(this T generic, IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    if(collection==null || collection.Count()==0) return false; // just for sure
    return collection.Contains(generic);
}
```

it is typed by `T` which can be any type, now you can write:

```
var list = new List<double>() {1,2,3,4};
double a = 1;
bool isIn = a.IsIn(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

If **only** value types are desired

```
public static bool IsIn(this ValueType integer, IEnumerable<int> collectionOfIntegers)
{
....
}
```

Comment: I think it's not generic.

Comment: @wudzik The OP said: "But what if I dont want to make it generic ...". Read the question.

Comment: and used generics tag. BTW read question to the end: `for each value type or object` is object value type?